# How do I apply the Fast Multipole Method to Thin Plate Spline interpolation?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, interpolation

I have n scattered measurements of elevation, z, as a function of x and y coordinate: $ \{(x_i,y_i,z_i)\}_{i=1..n}$ that I want to interpolate so that I find z(x,y) for all x and y.

Using [Thin Plate Splines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thin_plate_spline):

$$ z(x,y) = \sum_i l_i\phi(r)\tag{1}$$

where $\ \phi = r^2\ln(r) $ and $ r = \sqrt{(x_i-x)^2+(y_i-y)^2} $.

The interpolation has two steps:

**I Find the coefficients**

Demand that the interpolated curve goes exactly trough the measurements:
$$ z_i = \Phi_{ij}l_j \tag{2}$$ where $ \Phi_{ij}=r_{ij}ln(r_{ij})$ and $r_{ij}=\sqrt{(x_i-x_j)^2+(y_i-y_j)^2}$.

Solve this for l.

**II Add up contributions from all "sources"**

For any point (x,y) use equation (1) to find z.

This works fine but does not scale well with increasing n since the matrix in (2) is dense.
I quickly run out of RAM and solving the matrix equation is slow.

To the rescue [The Fast Multipole Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_multipole_method)!?

Consider 10 random xy points. Partition the xy space into boxes using a [Quadtree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree):

[image]

Approximate the points within a box by the center:
$$ l_c= \Sigma_{i} l_i $$
where i is over the points within the box only:
[image]

Here the contributions from the 3 "sources" in the box 2<=x<=4, 0<=y<=2 are considered to be far away, R >> r, from the point in question: x=6.8,y=5 and can therefore be approximated by a combined "source" in the center of the box.

Consider one box of size $\Delta x * \Delta y $.

**What is the max error from using the center point as a function of distance from point to center, R?**

Introduce $$ \beta = r/R \tag{3}$$
Taylor approximation around $ \beta = 0 $:
$$ (R+\beta R)^2ln(R+\beta R) = R^2ln(R) + \beta R^2(2ln(R)+1) + O(\beta^2)$$
Thus error of using a "source" in R instead of R + r can be approximated:

$$ \Delta z_i \approx l_i*\beta R^2(2ln(R)+1) $$

Relative error:
$$ \Delta z_i/l_i \approx \beta R^2(2ln(R)+1) \tag{4}$$

Demand that relative error is less than some threshold $ \epsilon $ e.g.: 1e-3.

Worst case: all points in one corner:
$$ r = \sqrt{(\Delta x/2)^2+(\Delta y/2)^2} \tag{5}$$

With a formulae for the max error I can speed-up step II by the following algorithm:

```
function visitBox(box):
  r = sqrt(0.25*dx*dx+0.25*dy*dy) 
  beta = r/R
  relError = beta*R*R*(2*ln(R)+1)
  if relError > epsilon:
     foreach child:
        visitBox(child) 
  else
      Z = Z + lc*R*ln(R)
epsilon = 1e-3
Z = 0
visitBox(root)
```

**But how do I use this approach to overcome the problems with step I?**

I understand that I can simplify a given row in (1) so that the number of elements are far less than n. However the simplification will vary from row to row and as a result
the matrix $ \Phi_{ij} $ will still be nxn. In fact it will be even larger since it must include centroid contributions. If there are m centroids; the size of this matrix will be (m+n)^2. But it will be sparse. And that is the key I guess?

Comment: I don't really understand the question. It seams to me that you are trying to do [Barnes-hut](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barnes%E2%80%93Hut_simulation) style approximation but for thin-plates, for which I think it is not a good idea. I can only direct you to [the short course on FMM](https://www.google.cz/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CD8QFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmath.nyu.edu%2Ffaculty%2Fgreengar%2Fshortcourse_fmm.pdf&ei=q6HQUZHJOoTvsgabh4CgAQ&usg=AFQjCNG6oCADmv-zn0sGVC1UFEORyowVNw&sig2=APiub4kCe0ULZYRW7XwBwg&bvm=bv.48572450,d.Yms)

Comment: Why is this not a good idea for thin-plates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I'll answer why is not good idea to do Barnes-hut style approximation with thin plates.

Barnes-hut is used for faster galaxy simulation so we(in 2d) want to calculate  this sum fast:

$$ \phi(x) = - \sum_{t=1}^N m_i \log(\|x-x_i\|)$$

in FMM(in 2d) we use complex numbers so

$$ \phi(x) = -\Re\left(  \sum_i m_i \log(x-x_i)\right)$$

where $x,x_i\in \mathbb{C}$.

Now assume that $\|x\|>\|x_i\|$, this corresponds to the situation when you want to evaluate the field caused by points($x_i$) in certain box(which is centered at origin) and you($x$) are far from it, so:

$$\sum_i m_i\log(x-x_i)= $$
$$\sum_i m_i\log(x) +m_i \log(1-\frac{x_i}{x})= $$
$$ \log(x)\sum_i m_i - \sum_i m_i \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x_i^n}{x^nn} =$$
$$\log(x)\sum_i m_i - \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{x^nn}\sum_i m_i x_i^n$$

The idea of FMM is to truncate the infinite sum to $K$ terms and calculate sums $\sum_i m_ix_i^n$ beforehead. So when evaluating $\phi$ you do work proportional to $K$ not to $N$.

so when you want to calculate $\phi$ calculate only

$$\log(x)\sum_i m_i - \sum_{n=1}^K \frac1{x^nn}\sum_i m_i x_i^n$$

Now if you do very rough approximation you pick $K=0$ so you get:

$$\phi(x) = \log(x)\sum_i m_i$$

So this is your $\sum_i l_i$

But now look what happens for thin plates:

$$ f(x) = \sum_i w_i \|x-x_i\|^2 \log \|x-x_i\|$$

using complex numbers you can rewrite it like ($x,x_i \in \mathbb{C}$)

$$ f(x) = \Re\left( \sum_i w_i (x-x_i)(x-x_i)^*\log(x-x_i)\right)$$

Assume that $\|x\|>\|x_i\|$:

$$ \sum_i w_i (x-x_i)(x-x_i)^* \log(x-x_i) = $$
$$ \sum_i w_i (x-x_i)(x-x_i)^* (\log(x)+ \log(1-\frac{x_i}{x})=$$
$$ \sum_i w_i (xx^* -x^*x_i - xx_i^* + x_ix_i^*)\left(\log(x) - \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x_i^n}{x^nn}\right)= $$

Now get rid of the infinite sum(picking $K=0$) as before and you get

$$f(x) \approx \Re\left( \log(x)\sum_i w_i (xx^* -x^*x_i - xx_i^* + x_ix_i^*) \right)$$

but this is different from

$$f(x) \approx \Re\left( xx^*\log(x)\sum_i w_i \right)$$

Comment: Thank you Tom for your help, but I still do not get this; why do you need to work with complex numbers? Both your case: ln(r) and my case: rln(r) are real since r>=0. Does this have to do with you doing a nearfield approximation using Laurent series? I am only considering the farfield case, where Taylor converges. In the nearfield region I do not approximate, but use the function itself.

Comment: The reason why we need complex numbers is because we use the Laurent series expansion. I would say that I'm doing far field approximation I have condition $\|x\|>\|x_i\|$ where $x_i$ are source points so the $x$ is 'far' from source points.

Comment: Well I think about Taylor expansion as local expansion, just around a single point. And about Laurent expansion as expansion around an infinity. Taylor series really gives you near field expansion.

Comment: Yes, but I have turned things around by introducing b=r/R. Since r << R in the farfield: b << 1. Pasting: Series[(R+b*R)*log(R+b*R),{b, 0, 0}] into wolfram alpha will show you that this converges for b < 1.

Comment: I think Taylor can always be used this way to do either a near field or a far field approximation. The power of Laurent series I think is that they can do both nearfield and farfield with the same approximation. However I am only interested in the farfield.

Comment: And mine converges when $\frac{\|x_i\|}{\|x\|} < 1$ so?

Comment: I am not comfortable using Laurent series. It has been a long time since I studied. I do not understand what they bring to the table in this case. They only seem to complicate things.

Comment: Well you can try it your way. It might work I'm not sure. But if you want full power of FMM have a look at the short course in FMM a posted before.

Comment: OK. Thanks again Tom!